# Loading tiny_mce.js with Ajax and initiate TinyMCE

Tags: ajax, tinymce

I'm trying to load tinyMCE with Ajax, the reason is that I don't want every visitor of the needing to load tinyMCE.

This is the code I'm using

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url:settings.script+"lib/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js",
  dataType: "script"
}).done(function() {
    rapport("tiny_mce.js loaded... trying to initiate..");        
    tinyMCE.init({
         mode : "textareas",
         theme : "advanced",
         other:"settings...",
         oninit:function() { console.log("editor initiated, running callback..."); }
        });
}).fail(function() { 
    errorRapport("failed loading tiny_mce.js");        
});
```

If I check tinyMCE with console.log I dint the function, but nothing happens when I try to execute it, and I tried both mode:"exact" and mode:"exact" with pointing to a existing textarea in the dom. I don't get any error messages, and the callback is never executed, anyone got a solution how to include the tiny_mce.js and got the Editor to run with an Ajax request of tiny_mce.js?

love & flow ~ Pontus

Comment: need to insert tiny_mce.js into DOM before try initializing tinyMCE.init()

Comment: Do you got any solution how I do that when loading tiny_mce.js with Ajax?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/How-to_load/save_with_Ajax_in_TinyMCE) you will find a Howto in the tinymce documentation, that shouls answer your question fully.

Comment: You obesely did't read my question, I don't have a problem with loading the content with Ajax, I wanna load tiny_mce.js with Ajax.

Comment: you need to load the tiny_mce.js into the DOM as Srikanth Kshatriy pointed out